# Reading proxy link within react app from package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, package.json

I am using react-app and have configured my package.json such as this.

```
{
  "proxy": "http://mybackend-prod.com"
}
```

But I have two endpoints, such as http://mybackend-prod.com and http://mybackend-dev.com,
And I wanted to have some tag overlay clearly differentiating Dev and Prod environments, based on this proxy link.